# Why am I receiving InvalidOAuthFlowException when I'm not setting an OAuthFlow in Cognito API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to write a java function to integrate with the Cognito API but I'm getting this exception:

> 09/06/2023 16:02:26  com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidOAuthFlowException: profile is not supported with client_credentials flow (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidOAuthFlowException; Request ID: ID)

This is the function I have written, though:

```
            CreateUserPoolClientRequest req = new CreateUserPoolClientRequest();
            
            req.setUserPoolId(userPoolId);
            req.setClientName(appName);
            
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add("profile");
            scopes.add("email");
            
            req.setAllowedOAuthScopes(scopes); 
            
            CreateUserPoolClientResult result = idProviderClient.createUserPoolClient(req);
```

As you can see, I have not set Allowed OAuth Flow, only Allowed OAuth Scopes. Going by this documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html), AllowedOAuthFlow is not required, so I don't see where this exception is coming from.

If I don't set the AllowedOAuthScopes the function is successful, but I want to set them. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some time I finally understood that I was just not reading the documentation correctly, the OAuthFlow is being set automatically as "client_credentials", which doesn't support these scopes for some reason. After I set the OAuthFlow to "code" it started working.

In case anyone comes across this in the future and uses it as reference, I also had to set OAuthFlowsUserPoolClient to "true" and add the scope "openid" to be able to use "profile" and "email". It ended up like this:

```
  CreateUserPoolClientRequest req = new CreateUserPoolClientRequest();
            
  req.withSupportedIdentityProviders("COGNITO");
  req.withAllowedOAuthFlows("code");
  req.setAllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient(true);
  req.withAllowedOAuthScopes("openid", "profile", "email"); 

  req.withLogoutURLs("https://"+ appName +".com");
  req.withCallbackURLs("https://"+ appName +".com");
  req.setDefaultRedirectURI("https://"+ appName +".com");

  req.setUserPoolId(userPoolId);
  req.setClientName(appName);
  req.setGenerateSecret(true);          
  
  CreateUserPoolClientResult result = idProviderClient.createUserPoolClient(req);
```

The exception itself was coming from the "client_credentials" being set as default, though.